# How to change Map.animateCamera() to Map.moveCamera() conditionally?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using maps in my android app. I have MapsActivity as my launcher activity when I navigate to a different activity and back home (i.e. MapsActivity) then camera ***animates*** to the current location. I want ***moveCamera*** instead of animateCamera. So, I want to change animateCamera method to moveCamera conditionally like when the app starts it should use ***animateCamera*** and after that, it will use ***moveCamera***

Is it the right approach to do this task? If not, tell me the best way to implement this in my app

Here is my **MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

// toolbar instance
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
RelativeLayout rootLayout;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;


//Request code
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1998;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST_CODE = 1999;

//Google APi client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrentMarker;
private GoogleMap mMap;
double lattitude, longitude;

//Map intervals
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

//Firebase
DatabaseReference mUserDatabase, locationDatabaseRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    //Custom Toolbar
    mToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("No Title");

    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerlayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_home);

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationAccount) {

                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationSettings) {

                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
            }
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigationContact) {

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //set contentView
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );

    // Firebase initialization
    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    locationDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Locations");

    setUpLocation();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (checkPlayServices()) {

                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    displayLocation();

                }
            }

            break;

    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestRuntimePermission();
    } else {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
            displayLocation();
        }
    }
}

private void displayLocation() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lattitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        //Updating to firebase

        locationDatabaseRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .setValue(new Tracking(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                        mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                        String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),
                        String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())));


        mCurrentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude))
                .title("You are Here"));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude , longitude) , 12.02f));
       // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude), 12.02f));
    }

}

private void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_REQUEST_CODE).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

private void requestRuntimePermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.connect_item) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Make Connection");
        dialog.setMessage("Please use ID shown in profile");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View connect_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connect_layout, null);

        final MaterialEditText connectID = connect_layout.findViewById(R.id.connect_id);

        dialog.setView(connect_layout);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                //validation
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(connectID.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter ID", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return;
                }

                mUserDatabase.orderByChild("uniqueID").equalTo(connectID.getText().toString())
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                                    // giving connected user data Log.d("QueryLog",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                    // Getting lattitude and longitude
                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Yo ! Connected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "User Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        });


        // this is cancel btn for dialog
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }

    // Logout is here

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent MainIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(MainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    // Profile item is here

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profile_item) {
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(profileIntent);
    }

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return true;

}
```

}

Here is my **MapsActivity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <include layout="@layout/main_app_bar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cast_libraries_material_featurehighlight_inner_radius">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_page_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you just tell your requirement ?

Comment: when app starts it should zoom camera to current location after that it never zoom in map every time when I navigate to home page (i.e. MapsActivity) but show current location

Comment: okay , i got you , just post your activity code here , i will help you with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in your mapActivity

```
//declare a global boolean 
boolean hasAnimated = false;
```

now in `displayLocation()`

```
if(!hasAnimated){
  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude , longitude) , 12.02f));
  hasAnimated = true;
}else{
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude), 12.02f));
}
```

this will do. :)

Comment: Above code will work if you are not killing MapsActivtity by which i mean not calling `finish()` method anywhere in `MapsActivity`.